# GCC Posistion independent code: Variables are not loaded correctly

Tags: c, gcc, position-independent-code

The Program works fine as a stand alone on CC2650 (M3). But it shall be used also as a firmware which is loaded over the radio channel. For this purpose the position independent code is needed. The problem is, all of the variables defined as described below are not set.

```
uint32_t u32Timer_g = 2000;

static DeviceInterfaceStructure_t suInterfaceStructure_g = 
{
  .timeOut = 0,                        
  .state = STATE_IDLE,                                                  
  .lastState = STATE_IDLE,              
  .Config.reconnect = 0,          
  .Config.lVersion = 0x01,        
};
```

The Program is compiled with GCC (gcc-arm-none-eabi-7-2018-q2-update) using the following flags:

```
--asm
-fPIE
-pie
-fno-strict-aliasing
-fdata-sections
-ffunction-sections
-fno-exceptions
```

and using the following linker script

```
ENTRY( ResetISR )

    MEMORY
{
    CRC (RX)        : ORIGIN = 0x00001000, LENGTH = 0x00000004
    OHD (RX)        : ORIGIN = 0x00001004, LENGTH = 0x0000000C
    INT_VEC (RX)    : ORIGIN = 0x00001010, LENGTH = 0x000000C8
    FWU_DESCR (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x000010D8, LENGTH = 0x00000040
    APP_DESCR (RX)  : ORIGIN = 0x00001118, LENGTH = 0x00000040
    FLASH (RX)      : ORIGIN = 0x00001158, LENGTH = 0x0000AF2F
    SRAM (RWX)      : ORIGIN = 0x20000000, LENGTH = 0x00005000
    /* Application can use GPRAM region as RAM if cache is disabled in the CCFG
    (DEFAULT_CCFG_SIZE_AND_DIS_FLAGS.SET_CCFG_SIZE_AND_DIS_FLAGS_DIS_GPRAM = 0) */
    GPRAM (RWX)     : ORIGIN = 0x11000000, LENGTH = 0x2000
}

/*. Generate a link error if heap and stack donâ€™t fit into RAM .*/
_Min_Heap_Size = 0x800;
_Min_Stack_Size = 0x800;

/*. Highest address of the stack. Used in startup file .*/
_estack = ORIGIN(SRAM) + LENGTH(SRAM); /*end of SRAM .*/

REGION_ALIAS("REGION_TEXT", FLASH);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_BSS", SRAM);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_DATA", SRAM);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_STACK", SRAM);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_HEAP", SRAM);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_ARM_EXIDX", FLASH);
REGION_ALIAS("REGION_ARM_EXTAB", FLASH);


/* Section allocation in memory */

SECTIONS
{
    .SHADOW_CRC :
    {
        KEEP(*(.SHADOW_CRC))
    } > CRC = 0xFF

    .IMAGE_HEADER :
    {
        KEEP(*(.IMAGE_HEADER))
    } > OHD = 0xFF

    .intvec :
    {
        KEEP(*(.vectors))
    } > INT_VEC = 0xFF

    .firmwareDescr :
    {
        KEEP(*(.firmwareDescr))
    } >  FWU_DESCR = 0xFF

    .applicationDescr :
    {
        KEEP(*(.applicationDescr))
    } >  APP_DESCR = 0xFF

    .text :
    {
        _text = .;
        *(.text*)
        *(.rodata)
        *(.rodata*)
        *(.init)
        *(.fini*)
        *(.eh_frame*)
        _etext = .;
    } > FLASH = 0xFF

   .ARM.exidx :
    {
        __exidx_start = .;
        *(.ARM.exidx* .gnu.linkonce.armexidx.*)
        __exidx_end = .;
    } > FLASH

    .ARM.extab :
    {
        *(.ARM.extab* .gnu.linkonce.armextab.*)
    } > FLASH

    .data :
    {
        _data = .;
        *(vtable)
        *(.data)
        *(.data*)
        _edata = .;
        *(.got)
        *(.got*)
        *(.igot*)
    } > SRAM AT > FLASH
    _ldata = LOADADDR(.data);

    .bss :
    {
        __bss_start__ = .;
        _bss = .;
        *(.bss*)
        *(COMMON)
        _ebss = .;
        __bss_end__ = .;
    } > SRAM


    /* User_heap_stack section, used to check that there is enough SRAM left */

    ._user_heap_stack :
    {
        __heap_start__ = .;
        end = __heap_start__;
        _end = end;
        __end = end;
        KEEP(*(.heap))
        __heap_end__ = .;
        __HeapLimit = __heap_end__;
        . = . + _Min_Stack_Size;
    } > SRAM

    .gpram :
    {
    } > GPRAM

}
```

The question is: What I'm doing wrong???

**Update**
The initialisation and realocation:

```
//*****************************************************************************
void
ResetISR(void)
{
    uint32_t *pui32Src, *pui32Dest;

    //
    // CC26xx PG1 workaround: Check backdoor when coming from POR
    //
    EnableAndCheckBackdoor();

    //
    // Final trim of device
    //
    trimDevice();
    
    //
    // Copy the data segment initializers from flash to SRAM.
    //
    pui32Src = &_etext;
    for(pui32Dest = &_data; pui32Dest < &_edata; )
    {
        *pui32Dest++ = *pui32Src++;
    }

    //
    // Zero fill the bss segment.
    //
    __asm("    ldr     r0, =_bss\n"
          "    ldr     r1, =_ebss\n"
          "    mov     r2, #0\n"
          "    .thumb_func\n"
          "zero_loop:\n"
          "        cmp     r0, r1\n"
          "        it      lt\n"
          "        strlt   r2, [r0], #4\n"
          "        blt     zero_loop");

   //
   // Call the application's entry point.
   //
   main();

    //
    // If we ever return signal Error
    //
    FaultISR();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code that does your zero init and data section relocation at startup? You likely have a bug there or something that doesn't match when using different boot methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though you compiled your code position independent, your linker script makes it not-that-way. Your data relocation loop uses flash addresses to do the data copy:

```
pui32Src = &_etext;
```

You need to modify that to handle the OTA case and copy the initialized data over from wherever it is in RAM.

Comment: The code works, but only on the adderess given in Linker Script (0x1000). If the Image is stored on an another address (0xC000) the initualisation script uses the wrong position in flash during the copy operation to the ram.
The libs are compiled with -fpic, the executable compiled with -fpie and all together is linked using -pie.

Comment: Yes, that's because your linker script says to do that. Change the code so it doesn't rely on constant symbols from the linker script if that's what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Unfortunately I dont know how I shall change the code that it works. Could You give some advice? I have already written an assembler script, that correct the varibles copy, dependent on the image location. But this workaround does not correct all of mistakes :( The code stucks little bit later as without correction.

Comment: You need to write position independent code - build your binary so you know where the data section is and copy it to the right place. If you need to do the same for the code/rodata section, do that too. Just don't depend on fixed globals if that's what you're trying to avoid.